# How to get Explorer sort by Name to sort folder and folder shortcuts together?

Tags: windows-7

Here Explorer sort by Name separates folder and folder shortcuts.

[image]

How can I remedy this i.e. get it to sort them together?

EDIT: Clarification: I want the sorting to remain otherwise unchanged, i.e. not to change the sorting of folders with respect to non-folder-shortcut files.

Comment: What is wrong with the sorting in your example?

Comment: Sorry - faulty example, now corrected.

Comment: "This question already has an answer here: Windows Explorer sorts files and folders separately" That's incorrect. That question is about folders and files generally and none of the answers there answer this question, which is specifically about folders and folder shortcuts. "This question has been asked before" That too is incorrect, as far as I can see. If you have a link to a previous instance of this question about folders and folder shortcuts, please post it.

Answer (score 2):

#### How can I get Explorer "Sort by Name" to sort folder and folder shortcuts together?

This is not possible with explorer.

You can get close **as long as you don't mind other kinds of files in the sorted list as well** (a folder shortcut is a file not a folder).

---

#### Explorer solution

Right click "Group by" > "Name"

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

---

#### XYplorer Solution

Right click "Sort by" > Untick "Sort Folders Apart"

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

> XYplorer is a tabbed file manager for Windows. It features a powerful file search, a versatile preview, a highly customizable interface, optional dual pane, and a large array of unique ways to efficiently automate frequently recurring tasks. It's fast and light, it's innovative, and it's portable.
>
> - Supported Operating Systems: Windows 10, Server 2014, 8.1, 8, Server 2012, 7, Server 2008, Vista, XP, Server 2003, 2000, NT, Me, 98;
>   32-bit and 64-bit versions.
> - XYplorer is a Portable File Manager. It doesn't require any installation or changes to your system or registry. Take it with you
>   and start it from a USB stick, along with your personal configuration.
>   File management to go.

Source [xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php)

There is a freeware version.

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [xyplorer](http://www.xyplorer.com/index.php) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: "This is not possible with explorer." OK, thanks. "You can get close as long as you don't mind other kinds of files in the sorted list as well " I do mind - hence that my question was specifically about folders and folder shortcuts.

Comment: The reason you can't is that folder shortcuts are just files, like any other file.

Comment: "folder shortcuts are just files, like any other file" Not quite. They have a specific extension -- .lnk.

Comment: That pedantic distinction doesn't help solve your issue. You can't make files sort as if they were directories **regardless of what extension they may or may not have**.

Comment: @ChrisJJ There are many ways to distinguish different files (not just the extension). None of those ways turn a file into a directory.

Comment: Your particular requirements are not achievable - unless of course you want to write your own version of explorer. I've told you how to get close.

Comment: "None of those ways turn a file into a directory" Thanks, but turning a file into a directory was not requested.

Comment: Agreed, you didn't explicitly ask for for that. You want explorer to behave in a way that treats links as directories for the purposes of sorting. That is not possible (I've explained why). I've given you the closest possible alternative and I've noted you can write a replacement for explorer that does what you want. I'm not sure what more you expect - other than a miracle ;)